# Exception in iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I have created an application for capture image from camera. This is my code

```
 -(IBAction) showCameraUI {
    BOOL hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = hasCamera ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

And implemented this delegate method for get the captured image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *yourImageView = image;
}
```

Implemented this method if user cancel the controller

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But it shows this exception. Does anyone have any idea why it is showing such exception after executing last line of function showCameraUI.

```
UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device. 2013-02-07 
10:06:06.976 CaptureImage[460:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be 
presented via UIPopoverController'
```

Comment: Something is wrong, because I see the question title as _“UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device for iPad”_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding the exception, the error message is very clear. *"On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController"* For iPad, you should present it in a `UIPopoverController` instead of using `[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`. This should fix the issue.

For eg:-

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    self.popover = popover;
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

**Edit:** As mentioned by @rmaddy, camera can be presented modally. The above is applicable when `sourceType` is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

Comment: yeah i tried this but it shows this exception NSInvalidArgumentException reason: 'Applicatin tried to present modally an active controller'

Thanks a lot for your Help.

Comment: Just try this alone `UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];`. And dont use this line at all `[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];`

Comment: it shows 'NSGenericException' reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.

i am new to ios developer so i want some help to improve my skill where should i start my learning i just read a book 'Beginning iPad Application Development' where to go from here

Comment: @ACB The requirement to use a popover is only true for picking images from the photo library. The camera can be presented modally if full screen.

Comment: @Arun You need to store the `popover` in property. That way it will not be deallocated. After the popover dismisses set it to nil (in callback).

Comment: @Arun, As iMartin said, you need to retain the popover, I have modified my answer to show that. Declare an `@property` for popover and use it as shown in answer. If you are a beginner, I would recommend you to go through [Raywenderlich iPhone Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Comment: it's not showing any exception or error but how can i check it's working or not

Comment: @Arun, So when you are running in iPad and using this feature, are you getting any errors? If not, are you able to open the photo album/camera?

Comment: i am not getting any error in iPad simulator but my code does not call the other two delegate function that is "imagePickerController" & "imagePickerControllerDidCancel" thats why is asked so

Comment: @Arun, Check if `picker.delegate = self;` is present and make sure you have implemented the corresponding delegate methods in self.

Comment: Also check if you have added `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` like this in your viewcontroller, `@interface viewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>`. Here is an iOS 4 [tutorial on this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)

Answer (score 5):

@Arun 
i am also face the same problem add global property in header file.

I hope the below code is useful for you

```
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   [imgPicker setDelegate:self];
   [imgPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
   [imgPicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
   [imgPicker setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];

   UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
   popOver.delegate = self;
   self.popoverImageViewController = popOver;
   [self.popoverImageViewController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 40) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

In that header file create global property like this

```
@property (strong) UIPopoverController *popoverImageViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift with iOS11:

```
            videoEditor.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            self.present(picker, animated: true)

            let popover = picker.popoverPresentationController
            popover?.sourceView = self.view

            // then config popover frame and arrow style here
```