# Capturing an image from camera on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

have created an application for capture image from camera. This is my code

```
-(IBAction) showCameraUI {
    BOOL hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = hasCamera ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

And implemented this delegate method for get the captured image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *yourImageView = image;
}
```

Implemented this method if user cancel the controller

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController*)picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But it shows this exception. Does anyone have any idea why it is showing such exception after executing last line of function showCameraUI.

> UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device. 2013-02-07 
>   10:06:06.976 CaptureImage[460:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be 
>   presented via UIPopoverController'

Comment: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

Comment: i tried this and still getting a exception

Comment: it shows 'NSGenericException' reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible @Jeff

Comment: Well, that error is kind of self-explanatory as well?

Comment: i am new to ios developer so i want some help to improve..so can u please help me @Jeff

Comment: Wow...magic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744927/uistatusbarstyleblacktranslucent-is-not-available-on-this-device-for-ipad ......same to same :P :P :P

Comment: @iPatel can u please help me in this

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
 }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE]; 

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DoImageConversionInBackGround:) withObject:img ];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls Try this

//  Pick an image from album

```
- (IBAction)imageFromAlbum:(id)sender
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

//  Take an image with camera

```
- (IBAction)imageFromCamera:(id)sender
{
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


//  Dismiss the image picker on selection and use the resulting image in our ImageView


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(    UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [imageField setImage:image];
}
```

//  On cancel, only dismiss the picker controller

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [imagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```